# "Dummy output" and no sound after recent updates

Tags: sound, output

I know this question has been asked before but none of the typical solutions are working for me. Something happened recently (not sure what) that caused the sound to stop working. My bluetooth headset still works but the sound from the speakers doesn't.

Please let me know what sort of diagnostic info that may be useful. Not really sure what to do at this point.

I've tried solutions like `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` and various other similar things but none of it works.

Thank you!

Laptop: HP Spectre x360

Output of lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0b) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 182 Memory at 6042000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M] Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] I/O ports at 4000 [size=64] [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: i915 Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16 Memory at 6043110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16 Memory at 6043129000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dfc (rev 30) (prog-if 00 [8250]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20 Memory at 6043122000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 30) (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 129 Memory at 6043100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: fast devsel Memory at 6043120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K] Memory at 6043128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K] Capabilities:

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0034 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16 Memory at 604311c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de8 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16 Memory at 4010000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de9 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17 Memory at 4010001000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 157 Memory at 6043125000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: mei_me Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dba (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: 78300000-783fffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123 Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0 I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00006fff Memory behind bridge: 60000000-760fffff Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006000000000-0000006021ffffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db0 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124 Bus: primary=00, secondary=3b, subordinate=3b, sec-latency=0 I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff Memory behind bridge: 77000000-780fffff Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006030000000-0000006041ffffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db4 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125 Bus: primary=00, secondary=3c, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: 78200000-782fffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16 Memory at 6043118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Memory at 6043000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255 Memory at 6043124000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256] I/O ports at efa0 [size=32] Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 30) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: fast devsel Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131 Memory at 78300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Physical Slot: 8 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16 Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0 I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff Memory behind bridge: 60000000-760fffff Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006000000000-0000006021ffffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126 Bus: primary=03, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: 76000000-760fffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127 Bus: primary=03, secondary=05, subordinate=39, sec-latency=0 I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff Memory behind bridge: 60000000-75efffff Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006000000000-0000006021ffffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode]) Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128 Bus: primary=03, secondary=3a, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0 Memory behind bridge: 75f00000-75ffffff Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: pcieport

04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16 Memory at 76000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K] Memory at 76040000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt Kernel modules: thunderbolt

3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 15db (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI]) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8518 Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 130 Memory at 75f00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

3b:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP108M [GeForce MX150] Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255 Memory at 77000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M] Memory at 6030000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] Memory at 6040000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M] I/O ports at 3000 [disabled] [size=128] Expansion ROM at 78000000 [disabled] [size=512K] Capabilities: Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express]) Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0001 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, NUMA node 0 Memory at 78200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] Capabilities: Kernel driver in use: nvme Kernel modules: nvme

Comment: same thing happened to me

Comment: Please add more information about your system and the output of `lspci .v`

Comment: I added the result to the post